# Search deep link for iTunes on iOS

Tags: ios, itunes-store

Is there a way (via a deep link) to navigate to the iTunes Store for a given set of keywords?

For example, I would like to dynamically create a link that searches for "Hey Jude" inside the iTunes Store, on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some really insightful search APIs here: https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching

Based on this, you can hit the search API, and then get the URL which leads to the iTunes Store being opened.